# How to delete from firebase realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase realtime database in Android app, and have data like this:
[image]

**How can i delete the record "Apple"** (marked in picture)?

According to the docs, to remove an item you call **removeValue()** on the reference. But to get the reference i require the child **id**. Because its a random generated id (*-KISNx87aYigsH3ILp0D*), how to delete it?

Comment: thanks to both for asking and answering #Amit & @Frank van Puffelen

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If you don't know the key of the items to remove, you will first need to query the database to determine those keys:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query applesQuery = ref.child("firebase-test").orderByChild("title").equalTo("Apple");

applesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot appleSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            appleSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: why i can't find `DatabaseReference`?

Comment: what if there are multiple nodes with title "Apple" ?

Comment: I think, you wrote that part getInstance().ref() accidently. That code should be FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

Comment: Good catch, fixed.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen if i want to get this object which has apple in it then what should i do in this onDataChanged method

Comment: @SumitJha either you limit query to first/last or any other depending upon your case or handle via your login in onDataChange

Answer (score 16):

this solved my problem

```
 mPostReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                        .child("quotes").child(mPostKey);
                mPostReference.removeValue();
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using firebase-admin you can simply try this out as

```py
admin.ref(`/users/${userid}`).remove()
```

and that works for me.

And also do remember to use `async` and `await` syntax.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this code :

```
onDeletePost(id:string){
return this.http.delete(`https://my-angular8-prjt.firebaseio.com/posts/${id}.json`).subscribe();
}
```

Comment: You should include details of what your answer does

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how and why you are deleting the data you can use these:

```
// Could store the push key or get it after push
String newPostKey = yourDatabase.child('firebase-test').push({
    something:something
}).key();

// Depends how you get to here
howYouGotHereId.parent().setValue(null);
```

[Firebase Save Data 3.0](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data#update_specific_fields)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that images is the directory of your firebase database which you want to clear.

```
private static DatabaseReference mDatabase;
public static void clearData(){
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabase.child("images").setValue(null);
}
```

Here images is the parent directory of the database. If you want to clear a nested directory (DCIM) inside the images directory so that you can retain the remaining data in it.

In that scenario you can do like this,

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.child("images").child("DCIM").setValue(null);
```

As a response to the query, Please try to use setValue method with null value `setValue(null)` to clear the data from firebase database

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Firebase admin with python though:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db
cred = credentials.Certificate("<your certificate>.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {'databaseURL': 'https://<your db>.firebaseio.com/'})

snapshot = db.reference('firebase-test').get()
for k,v in snapshot.items():
    if v['title'] == "Apple":
        db.reference('firebase-test').child(k).delete()
```